# Even though SMTP authentication enabled at Microsoft ADMIN portal, Not able to use microsoft email to send mail from Spring boot application, why?

Tags: smtp, office365

At Exchange admin portal SMTP authentication enabled.
Using plain username and password which used to login from the WEB.
Even though not able to send mail from Spring boot application

Config:

```
 spring.mail.host=smtp.office365.com
 spring.mail.port=587
 spring.mail.username=tech@domain.com
 spring.mail.password=xxxxxxxx
 spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
 spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Exception occured :

```
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
2023-08-03 13:52:31,552 ERROR [http-nio-3302-exec-1]com.project.app.exception.exceptionHandler: Exception Occured 
       org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; 
          nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. 
                        Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information.
```

Send mail to user specified at (TO)